# Beamer Handouts: 4 on 1 w/ adjusted positions, but page numbering incorrect

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to make Beamer handouts (either 4 on 1 or 8 on 1). Below is my MWE. I think the usual 4 on 1 has too much space between slides, with the slides too close to the margins (printing the handouts sometimes cuts off part of the slides). So I've included in my MWE a lot of code that I pulled from other questions on this site. **The page numbering is incorrect.** It was correct the first time I typeset it, but when I added more slides, things went crazy. How do I fix the page numbering?

```
\documentclass[12pt, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm, array}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through,arrows,shadows,backgrounds,mindmap,calendar}
\RequirePackage{latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PRESENTATIONS
%
%
% Background color
%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=red!20!yellow!25!}
%
%
% END OF PRESENTATION COMMANDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% HANDOUTS
%
%
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\def\strokeifnotempty{%
\expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
\let\@next=\relax
\else
\let\@next=\pgfstroke
\fi
\@next%
}
\makeatother

\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}

% 4 pages per sheet of paper
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{4 on 1 new}%[letterpaper, border shrink=12mm, landscape]
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{
logical pages=4, 
physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight, 
physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1.1pt}
\strokeifnotempty, 
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth, 
resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight, 
center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth + 10mm}{.75\pgfphysicalheight - 10mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1.1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth, 
resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight, 
center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth - 10mm}{.75\pgfphysicalheight - 10mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1.1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth, 
resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight, 
center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth + 10mm}{.25\pgfphysicalheight + 10mm}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{1.1pt}\strokeifnotempty, 
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder, 
resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth, 
resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight, 
center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth - 10mm}{.25\pgfphysicalheight + 10mm}
}
}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 new}[letterpaper, 
border shrink=12mm, landscape] \nofiles}{}
}

% Make a border around frames
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{ \tikz \draw[semithick] 
    (current page.north west) 
    rectangle 
    (current page.south east); }

%Page numbering for handouts
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{centered page number}
{%
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    {\color{black} \scriptsize \insertpagenumber \,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}%
    \hspace*{\fill}\vskip2pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[centered page number]
%
%
% END OF HANDOUT COMMANDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frenchspacing

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title Page
\begin{frame}[t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
%
Here's a slide.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
%
Here's a slide.
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `.aux` file, then compile twice.

Comment: I commented out the lines involving the .aux file, but then I didn't get handouts (4 slides per sheet of paper).

Comment: I mean you should try deleting the `.aux` file produced by a previous compilation run. Then compile the document again. Don't comment out anything.

Comment: So when I removed the .aux file only, the handouts became a PDF with only one slide per page. I compiled twice, and the page numbering was corrected. But then I had to add the .aux file back to the .tex file to make the 4-on-1 handouts (with the correct numbering). Is there a way to avoid doing all of that? I'm sorry if you're getting it to compile correctly on yours. If you are, add a few more slides so that the number of total slides isn't a multiple of 4. Are things still correct for you?

Comment: The number of slides does not have to be divisible by 4. The page numbering works fine every time if I have removed the `.aux` file after adding or removing slides. If I understand you correctly, you are commenting out and adding back parts of the `.tex` file that have to do with the `.aux`. Don't. Just remove the actual `.aux` file. Sorry, I don't have an automated solution for this.

Comment: It seems that option `handout` searches for an existing `\jobname.aux` file. If it exists will produce the `handout` version and not change existing `aux` file. If not will produce a `beamer` version and its corresponding `aux` file. This `aux` contains the total number of slides which is used in footer, and this number is only updated when `handout` is not used. So, it looks difficult to update it when adding new frames with `handout` option.